# CKEditor SetData Callback Doesn't Fire?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm calling the CKEditor function SetData per the CKE [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor), but the callback isn't firing.

**HTML**

```
<p><textarea id="CKEditorTextArea">original editor data</textarea>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
function tempCallBack(){
  alert('test');
  CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditorTextArea.setData( '<p>Callback was fired.</p>');
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{   
    CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditorTextArea');

    CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditorTextArea.setData( '<p>This data is placed into the editor, but the callback doesn\'t fire.</p>', {
            callback: function() {
                tempCallBack();
                this.checkDirty(); // true
            }
        } );
});
```

Isn't this weird? Shouldn't the callback fire?

A CodePen demonstrating this anomaly is [**here**](http://codepen.io/VikR/pen/QEWmEB).